# Restore jpeg file from its encoded64 code in Rails/Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, base64

Our question is that with Base64 encoded jpeg image file in `uploaded_io`, how to restore jpeg file out of it?

The encoded `uploaded_io` is generated by `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")`. Here is the `uploaded_io` looks like:

```
uploaded_io = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2....."
```

In ruby/rails 4, a `base64` encoded file could be decoded with:

```
require 'base64'
decoded = Base64.decode64(uploaded_io.sub(/.+,/, ''))  #removed file header 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' as suggested
```

We added the gem `mini_magick` ([v3.5.0](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#thinking-of-switching-from-rmagick)) and installed the `image magick` library on our computer. Did the following:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.new(decoded)
```

However the `image` is not a jpeg image file and does not respond well to `.type` and `.size`. There is no need to manipulate the image file and we are not sure that weather `mini_magick`/`image magick` are really needed here.

Comment: Can you save the base64 decoded value into a file with extension .jpg and see whether you can view it?

Comment: Not sure how to save decoded into a file. Did save decoded into a variable `img`. Only `img.size` returns an integer. `img.type` and `img.content_type` return error of `undefined method`.

Comment: Already someone has posted an answer on how to save decoded byte array to file.  I have independently tried to save the base64 part from image file into a file after decoding it,  I was able to view the file as  jpg in photo viewer app

Comment: `Wand Maker`,  saved the decoded with `File.open('my_img.jpeg', 'wb') {|f| f.write(img)}` and views it successfully. The decode64 works. (`img` was chopped the header). However not sure why the image attributes were not available as they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that stands out is your decoding the image then removing the header which will cause problems.

```
image = MiniMagick::Image(decoded.sub(/.+,/, ''))
```

I did a simple test encoding / decoding an image using Ruby `Base64` and everything worked as expected.

`irb` example:

```
require 'base64'

e = Base64.encode64(IO.read('/path/to/jpeg'))
d = Base64.decode64(e)

File.open("test.jpg", "w") { |f| f.write(d) }
```

`test.jpg` should be a valid file. Confirm by executing `file test.jpg`.

Comment: Our encoded64 is actually from `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")`. Is there a difference with `Base64.encode64()`?

Comment: Someone suggested removing the header before decode. The `Base64.encode64` does not create that header as I understood.

Comment: Just verified that decoding without chopped off the header does not show and has error.